# typescript deserialization on axios get request response object

Tags: typescript, deserialization, typescript2.0, axios

I have the following `axios` get request:

```
export function getCurrentCart() {
    return axios.get(Constants.ENDPOINT_MENU_TIMESLOTS, getConfig())
        .then(res => {
            let data = (res as AxiosResponse).data;
            if (data != null) {
                // parsing logic to singleton CartStore instance here
                ...
            } else {
                console.error("data is null");
            }
        });
}
```

which retrieves a ts `CartStore` class:

```
export class CartStore {
    id: number;
    temporaryTotal: number;
    status: string = "SHOPPING";
    statusLockTime?: any;
    updatedAt?: string;
    createdAt?: string;
    coupon?: Coupon;

    readonly items = observable.shallowArray<CartItem>([]);  // this is a mobx observable

    @computed get hasItem(): boolean {
        return this.items.length > 0;
    }

    @action clear() {
        this.items.clear();
    }
}
```

where `Coupon` and `CartItem` are the other model classes.

Here is the sample JSON response:

```
{
  "createdAt": "2017-02-16T20:37:13",
  "updatedAt": "2017-02-22T22:48:50",
  "id": 1,
  "status": "SHOPPING",
  "statusLockTime": null,
  "temporaryTotal": 0,
  "items": [
    ... array of some other json object
  ],
  "coupon": {
    ... json object
  }
}
```

Which deserializer librar(ies) do you guys recommend? Another question is: how to do it in the most TS way without using any library?